# How to automatically set checkbox to true when dropdownlist on change?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I have multiple group which each of them consist of a checkbox and a dropdownlist which group together, when the dropdown list for the particular group is changed then the checkbox also will automatically set to checked.

```
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group col-md-12">
          <span class="input-group-addon">
            <input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="1">
          </span>
            <select class="dateselectpicker form-control"id="filter"title="Filter">
                <option>a</option>
                <option>b</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>  

<div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group col-md-12">
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                <input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="2">
              </span>
                <select class="dateselectpicker form-control"id="filter1"title="Filter">
                    <option>a</option>
                    <option>b</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

For example, when i select the first filter, then the checkbox for first filter will set to checked. Only when dropdown list on change. How can i do this?

Updated: It is not working when selectpicker is applied.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it using `change` event listener in jquery like this

```js
$( "select" ).change(function() {
 $(this).prev(".input-group-addon").find(":checkbox").prop("checked",true);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group col-md-12">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
            <input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="1">
          </span>
      <select class="dateselectpicker form-control" id="filter" title="Filter">
                <option>a</option>
                <option>b</option>
            </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group col-md-12">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
                <input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="2">
              </span>
      <select class="dateselectpicker form-control" id="filter1" title="Filter">
                    <option>a</option>
                    <option>b</option>
                </select>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You might be doing something wrong coz it's working fine you can check the snippet also

Comment: Yeah, just curious why it is not working for me, because it is exactly same.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle for your code. I'll check what's wrong

Comment: i tried my code on jsfiddle, but it is working. Will it caused by other external resources?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159115/discussion-between-sanchit-patiyal-and-zidance).

Comment: may or may not can't say without looking into your code

Comment: only work if a normal dropdown, when it add $('.selectpicker').selectpicker(); then it is not working.